# Thought process \ formula to estimate ability to perform MySQL transactions

Tags: mysql

Is there a thought process and formula to ballpark the ability of a computer's maximum rate to process MySQL database transactions?

For example, if MySQL was running on a [Raspberry Pi 3](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b/), with a Class 10  SD card, how would one approximate the maximum rate of database transaction assuming:

1. A **transaction** consists of creating record of length X-bytes
2. performing Y-updates: a cycle of record-search and updates(4-bytes) to update the record and complete the transaction

Database transactions are sent through a network: bandwidth is not a bottleneck.  Bonus for commenting on typical bottlenecks.  If you have performed this test on a mySQL system, **please** state this in your reply.

As a starting point (in thought process) :I would expect the theoretical limit to be the clock rate (1.2 GHz), however this does not take into account many factors such as writing to the SD card and writing a tuple of X-bytes could require more than one clock cycle.

Any edits or questions to clarify the question are appreciated: Thank you

Comment: Have you done any stress testing of your own?  Even if you had a theoretical benchmark, you would still need tl test things for real.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to use MySQL on a Raspberry Pi for *occasional* transactions, then fine.

But if you're trying to run a high-throughput ACID database on a Pi, you will be disappointed. An ACID database is pretty demanding on the I/O system, the SD card on a Raspberry Pi is incredibly slow.

I answered in some detail in this related question: [MySQL poor performance in Centos 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41418232/mysql-poor-performance-in-centos-7/41418598#41418598). There is some performance variance between different brands of SD cards, but they are all way slower than a real I/O system.

As soon as you ask the question about how high a transaction rate you can support on a Pi, that's a clue that you need a server. Run the Pi as a client only, and send updates over the network to the database server.

I'm not a Pi developer, but I have experience as a performance consultant for MySQL on servers.